# Where is the list of valid specialties for Schema.org/MedicalSpecialty?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

The example on https://schema.org/MedicalCondition includes `"specialty": "http://schema.org/Cardiovascular"`. Where can I find a list of all the valid specialties? Can I insert an arbitrary value if the specialty I need is not defined on schema.org?

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to set new types of medical specialties using the property **[additionalType](https://schema.org/additionalType)**. To determine your medical specialties, you can use the Wikipedia list **[Specialty (medicine)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialty_(medicine))** and choose the specialty that suits you. To ontology a specialty, it may be useful to establish a URL for an article about this specialty from Wikipedia or (a more machine-readable version) from DBpedia. E.g., 
to Wikipedia:

`"additionalType":"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolescent_medicine"`

to DBpedia:

```
"additionalType":"http://dbpedia.org/page/Adolescent_medicine"
```